# How to solve problem with special characters such as "é" with R and RStudio?

Tags: r, csv, encoding, rstudio

I downloaded a new version of R (4.3.1) and RStudio (2023.06.1) on a new computer (PC W11) and since this download my old R Script files have been modified ("é" to "?") and I have having trouble reading my .csv files that contain special characters like "é"
Is there a encoding option on the RStudio configuration that I can change?
Thanks for your help your help

not that much
to be able to read my R Script file again

Comment: Hi, can you try the Sys.getenv("LANG") command in the r console ? If it's not equal to "en_US.UTF-8", try changing it so that your file's encoding is also in UTF8.

Comment: Hi @Nahalot, Here is the answer to Sys.getenv("LANG") -> [1] ""

Comment: > Sys.getenv("LANG")
[1] ""

Comment: Try this to set the LANG environment variable : Sys.setenv(LANG = "en_US.UTF-8")

Comment: Thank you Nahalot,
This does not seem to have solved the problem.
my script is always modified ("é" to "?")
### rows/columns database dimension
and I still have issues related to accents in my .csv files

Comment: Error in sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", x) : input string 1 is invalid
In addition: Warning message:
In sub("[[:space:]]+$", "", x) :
  unable to translate 'Fracture de la mal<e9>ole' to a wide string

Comment: If you run `writeLines("\u00e9")` at the RStudio console, does it print correctly? Have you tried explicitly setting the `encoding` parameter for `read.csv`?

Comment: Yes @Marcus it seems to encode correctly. I haven't try to explicitly setting the encoding parameter for read.csv and don't know how to do that

Comment: > writeLines("\u00e9")
é

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `Sys.getlocale()`. Maybe `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale=".65001")` could help?

Comment: Thanks @JosefZ for your answer. Here is the answer for Sys.getlocale()

Comment: "LC_COLLATE=French_France.utf8;LC_CTYPE=French_France.utf8;LC_MONETARY=French_France.utf8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.utf8

Comment: Hi,
Any other suggestions or help from R experts
Thanks